# ios 13 devices sending different session-id than received in the response from cookies

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, safari, session-cookies

When I am trying to login to my site by calling /authenticate method, I am receiving `sessionid=x` inside cookies. However for next req eg: `/getUserRole`, the the session id is not the same. for eg: `sessionid=y`. We are not modifying any cookie parameter at front end. This behavior is only occurring on `ios` devices ( ipad, mobiles ). For mac machine its working on google chrome but not not safari.

The session id validation is done in drupal. Also this is not working for a particular front end code base. For different front end code base its working fine. The only difference in that other frond end codebase is few `html` and `css` changes.